# Cant enable quotas on XFS file system

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, xfs, quota

I'm trying to enable quotas on Centos 7

I ran `yum install quota`

Edited fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults,usrquota,grpquota        0 0
UUID=6c443910-a7e9-4e97-8b51-de9d05407cf6 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

And rebooted

When I try to create quota files I get an error:

```
quotacheck -cug /
quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) / not found or has no quota enabled.
quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.
```

Comment: Try using the xfs tools, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsquota.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quota system for the XFS file system needs to be enabled and managed in a slightly different manner to how it is/was done with other file systems.

The mount option to enable quota is not `quota` but one or more of:

- uquota/uqnoenforce - User quotas
- gquota/gqnoenforce - Group quotas
- pquota/pqnoenforce - Project quota

Each mount option can also be specified as `<option>noenforce`; this will allow usage reporting without actually enforcing any quota limits.

Once enabled quota and usage can be managed and reported with the dedicated `xfs_quota` tool.